# JQuery DatePicker bundled control can't be included in other controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, web-user-controls, westwind

I've been tasked with implementing a Date/Time selector for several areas of our web project, and instructed to use a control that another developer created as part of it.  The control I'm working on is supposed to allow the user to choose a date from a calendar, choose a format for the display of that date (from several pre-defined formats, or with a simple text override) and optionally a time string (which is really just freeform text).

The control I was instructed to use is documented here: http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/213015.aspx, and uses the DatePicker from jQuery.

After I implemented my control and tested it, I began integrating it into the pages which needed Date and/or time inputs.  In my testing of those implementations, I discovered a bug: when I include multiple copies of my control on a page, only the first one gets the jQuery calendar.  The others are not tied to it.

I have tried some of the methods suggested in a seemingly-related question (titled 'duplicating jquery datepicker'), such as calling the '.datepicker()' function on the west-wind control (which renders a textbox) via the $("css-selector").datepicker() syntax, and ASP.NET is guaranteeing unique IDs for all the text boxes.

So, in summation, it looks like this:

```
<page>
  <mycontrol>
   <west-windjQuerycontrol />
  </mycontrol>
  <mycontrol>
   <west-windjQuerycontrol />
  </mycontrol>
</page>
```

Now, the strange part: When there are multiple copies of the west-wind control on the page, without the other user control containing them, they work correctly.  Other than the jQuery control, my control has nothing unusual about it: simply labels, textboxes, panels, and dropdowns.  Something about bundling the West-Wind jQuery control into a user control seems to be breaking it.

Any advice?  I've been banging my head against this for a while, hampered by my poor javascript skills and limited exposure to jQuery.

As pointed out below, it's hard to say without the HTML.  I've included it below.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="ControlTest.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTU4NjEzMDEwOQ9kFgICAw9kFgQCAw9kFgRmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIDDxBkZBYBZmQCAg9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAWZkAgUPZBYEZg9kFgICAw9kFgICAw8QZGQWAWZkAgIPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPEGRkFgFmZGRDjfLpdb+XxaVaQYP2XkPil2Galw=="     />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
        }
}
//]]>
</script>


        <script src="/SSO/DE/WebResource.axd?d=jMPpL-KK8_mPj_ssZzGblw2&amp;t=633481894229838141" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/SSO/DE/ScriptResource.axd?d=8KwRIGaNAD3hi2Loz3YV-uxgrdZpGe8nnwH5E3gxLW_lQpnYjRbyIYThTnHtD9rt0&amp;t=633613004148118290" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SSO/DE/ScriptResource.axd?d=8KwRIGaNAD3hi2Loz3YV-uxgrdZpGe8nnwH5E3gxLW-K0Kuw-pGK1O3mE_r1y3sjKmhHtQjSXeMtYSim0bjyGA2&amp;t=633613004148118290" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SSO/DE/ScriptResource.axd?d=Id5yAacLMZHF7TWlkgrrid30ZStmsXuLHcF6WQ404YLySP4Itj4qxv2wi9ffbsWQA86oLdnZPWkwDnu4NKxfG1Ue7qdGG1SbOfb4ooHVs7M1&amp;t=633481957084709567" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/SSO/DE/ScriptResource.axd?d=Id5yAacLMZHF7TWlkgrrid30ZStmsXuLHcF6WQ404YLySP4Itj4qxv2wi9ffbsWQhT3MFELBAa2rFJZXnSlYAZIN7RT1npcBxJRsWGjJWIwTF0Es1m0vOd-xYnFqWJKz0&amp;t=633481957084709567" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div style="margin:25px 10px;width:100%;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('stupidThing',     document.getElementById('form1'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls([], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>

        <div id="datePicker_Div0" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
            <div id="datePicker_Div1" class="DELabel">
                <span id="datePicker_DateLabel">Date</span>
            </div>
            <div id="datePicker_Div2" class="DEInput datePicker">
                <input name="datePicker$DateSelector" type="text" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$DateSelector\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="datePicker_DateSelector" style="width:80px;" />
                <select name="datePicker$languageSelector" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$languageSelector\',\'\')', 0)" id="datePicker_languageSelector">
    <option selected="selected" value="en-US">en-US</option>
    <option value="fr-CA">fr-CA</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">fr-FR</option>
    <option value="es-ES">es-ES</option>
    <option value="es-MX">es-MX</option>

</select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="datePicker_Div3" class="AdminRowEven DERow">
            <div id="datePicker_Div4" class="DELabel">
                <span id="datePicker_FormatChoiceLabel">Choose your display format:    </span>
            </div>
            <div id="datePicker_Div5" class="DEInput">
                <select name="datePicker$DateFormatSelector" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$DateFormatSelector\',\'\')', 0)" id="datePicker_DateFormatSelector">
    <option selected="selected" value="Choose a date first">Choose a date     first</option>

</select>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="datePicker_Div6" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
            <div id="datePicker_Div7" class="DELabel">
                <span id="datePicker_FormatOverrideLabel">Or enter your own     text</span>
            </div>
            <div id="datePicker_Div8" class="DEInput">
                <input name="datePicker$DateFormatOverride" type="text"     onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$DateFormatOverride\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;"     id="datePicker_DateFormatOverride" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div id="date1_Div0" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
            <div id="date1_Div1" class="DELabel">
                <span id="date1_DateLabel">Date</span>
            </div>
            <div id="date1_Div2" class="DEInput datePicker">
            <input name="date1$DateSelector" type="text" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$DateSelector\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="date1_DateSelector" style="width:80px;" />
                <select name="date1$languageSelector" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$languageSelector\',\'\')', 0)" id="date1_languageSelector">
    <option selected="selected" value="en-US">en-US</option>
    <option value="fr-CA">fr-CA</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">fr-FR</option>
    <option value="es-ES">es-ES</option>
    <option value="es-MX">es-MX</option>

</select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="date1_Div3" class="AdminRowEven DERow">
            <div id="date1_Div4" class="DELabel">
                <span id="date1_FormatChoiceLabel">Choose your display format:</span>
            </div>
            <div id="date1_Div5" class="DEInput">
                <select name="date1$DateFormatSelector" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$DateFormatSelector\',\'\')', 0)" id="date1_DateFormatSelector">
    <option selected="selected" value="Choose a date first">Choose a date first</option>

</select>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="date1_Div6" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
            <div id="date1_Div7" class="DELabel">
                <span id="date1_FormatOverrideLabel">Or enter your own text</span>
            </div>
            <div id="date1_Div8" class="DEInput">
                <input name="date1$DateFormatOverride" type="text" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$DateFormatOverride\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="date1_DateFormatOverride" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWFQLr6MeTCwKb1Zr0AwKVt6utCQKIwaTjAQKdwYzzBwLiwsDhDQKIwdCLBAKHwbCtCgLRr42cCQKi9vj4DgK2lM6kBQLLrsUtAsaboRMC2+2u3QgCzu2GzQ4Cse7K3wQC2+3atQ0C1O26kwMCpdTivwwC1o2X2wsCoubqnQk8I1BK30Q/iVw/rExUww2Cs4bicw==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
var cal = jQuery('#datePicker_DateSelector').datepicker({yearRange: '-1500:+100',dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});
} );
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok - i've added specific details as to why you are seeing the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know without seeing the generated HTML, but my first guess would be that your control isn't applying class names directly to the `<input>` field... or you are depending on `id`s in some way (which would likely change when embedded in a user control).

---

In the HTML you've posted, these appear to three relevant portions:

#### Block #1 (control: datePicker)

```
<div id="datePicker_Div0" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
    <div id="datePicker_Div1" class="DELabel">
        <span id="datePicker_DateLabel">Date</span>
    </div>
    <div id="datePicker_Div2" class="DEInput datePicker">
        <input name="datePicker$DateSelector" type="text" 
           onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$DateSelector\',\'\')', 0)" 
           onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" 
           id="datePicker_DateSelector" style="width:80px;" />
        <select name="datePicker$languageSelector" 
           onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'datePicker$languageSelector\',\'\')', 0)" 
           id="datePicker_languageSelector">
                <option selected="selected" value="en-US">en-US</option>
                <option value="fr-CA">fr-CA</option>
                <option value="fr-FR">fr-FR</option>
                <option value="es-ES">es-ES</option>
                <option value="es-MX">es-MX</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

#### Block #2 (control: date1)

```
<div id="date1_Div0" class="AdminRowOdd DERow">
   <div id="date1_Div1" class="DELabel">
       <span id="date1_DateLabel">Date</span>
   </div>
   <div id="date1_Div2" class="DEInput datePicker">
      <input name="date1$DateSelector" type="text" 
         onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$DateSelector\',\'\')', 0)" 
         onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" 
         id="date1_DateSelector" style="width:80px;" />
       <select name="date1$languageSelector" 
         onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'date1$languageSelector\',\'\')', 0)" 
         id="date1_languageSelector">
         <option selected="selected" value="en-US">en-US</option>
         <option value="fr-CA">fr-CA</option>
         <option value="fr-FR">fr-FR</option>
         <option value="es-ES">es-ES</option>
         <option value="es-MX">es-MX</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

...

#### Block #3 (jQuery datepicker wireup)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   jQuery(document).ready( function() 
   {
      // matches input element for first control only (id selector)
      var cal = jQuery('#datePicker_DateSelector')
         .datepicker({yearRange: '-1500:+100',dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});
   });
   Sys.Application.initialize();
   //]]>
</script>
```

The problem arises from this last block. The selector is specific to the first control, matching by ID. If it was modified to include a separate call for the second control...

```
      var cal = jQuery('#datePicker_DateSelector')
         .datepicker({yearRange: '-1500:+100',dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});
      var cal2 = jQuery('#date1_DateSelector')
         .datepicker({yearRange: '-1500:+100',dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});
```

...or a more general-purpose selector...

```
      // matches all text input elements that are descendants of 
      // a div element with a class of datePicker
      var cal = jQuery('div.datePicker input:text')
         .datepicker({yearRange: '-1500:+100',dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});
```

...then things should work as expected.

Comment: Excellent point, I've included the HTML.  I'll check the render methods and see if it is ID dependent.  I doubt the CSS-style javascript selection would be a problem, though, as the class would be applied, and the input nested (so ".datepicker input" would still hit it in CSS, and presumably JS)

Comment: (after edit) Thanks!  It looks like that is being rendered by the control that encapsulates the jQuery stuff...and only one render is firing.

Replacing the call as you described (hardcoded on the page) worked as expected, so now I have a going in position.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

The OnPreRender() of the server control builds the javascript found above, the calls the following, where sbStartupScript is a StringBuilder which contains the generated javascript:

```
sbStartupScript.AppendLine("} );");
scriptProxy.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(ControlResources), "_cal" + this.ID,
sbStartupScript.ToString(), true);
```

The correct form should have been:

```
sbStartupScript.AppendLine("} );");
scriptProxy.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(ControlResources), "_cal" + this.ClientID,
sbStartupScript.ToString(), true);
```

Now, having the ClientId, the script name is unique, and both will render.